# Can't use website domain as tomcat host name with port 80

Tags: firefox, tomcat, windows-7, tomcat7, socialauth

i am trying to run social auth library on my machine, so i followed steps in this link:

http://code.google.com/p/socialauth/wiki/HowToRunApplicationWithLocalhostOnWindows

1. in hosts file changed the binding of localhost: `127.0.0.1       opensource.brickred.com`.
2. in tomcat in eclipse, i changed the hostname to `opensource.brickred.com` and the HTTP port to 80.

when trying to run the application, i found out that it's trying to access the link:

```
opensource.brickred.com/myapp
```

online not on my localhost, and that the application is accessible only through:

```
localhost/myapp
```

the website domain is working only in case the port is 8080, through the following link:

```
http://opensource.brickred.com:8080/myapp/
```

please advise, how can i run my app on the new host name on port 80 ?

Comment: Two questions. 1) Why did you set `opensource.brickred.com` to be `127.0.0.1` instead of using standard DNS? and 2) Why did you bother changing Tomcat's hostname from `localhost` to anything else? The default configuration should work regardless of the hostname used by the client. Can you post your `<Host>` and `<Connector>` elements from `server.xml`>

Comment: @Christopher Schultz, this is the configuration to test socialauth on local machine as referenced above, and the link is http://code.google.com/p/socialauth/wiki/HowToRunApplicationWithLocalhostOnWindows

Comment: Again, post your configuration. The link above doesn't have a sample configuration... only terse instructions that you have not have executed properly.